# Need debugging approach for C# WinUI 3 desktop application

Tags: c#, debugging, crash, desktop, winui-3

I have a c# WinUI 3 desktop application (VS 2019) that uses a NavigationView.  I have been able to navigate to the different 'pages' of the menu successfully.  Now when I navigate to one particular page, the application will crash (i.e. disappear).  This occurs when I run the app via the Crtl+F5 debug option (Start Without Debugging).  However when I run the app with F5, (Start Debugging), it will not crash  when I navigate to the particular page, there are no exceptions thrown.  I have added a lot of try catch statements and debug.writeline statements in order to find why the app crashes when not in debug mode.  Is there some other way/approach/technique to find the exception that is causing the app to crash if I can't replicate the issue in debug mode?  Thank you so much StackOverFlow!

Comment: Try starting it up and then attaching a debugger

Comment: Create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and share it.

Comment: Since the problem seems to be inside that particular page, it shouldn't be difficult to locate which component is causing the problem. Try reducing the components inside the page.

Comment: Try winDBG Preview instead of Visual Studio https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugging-using-windbg-preview